# Using tex.get luatex function (segfault on Linux)?

Tags: luatex

Looking at [LuaTEX Reference Manual (luatexref-t.pdf)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/luatex/base/manual/luatexref-t.pdf), it says:

> 4.13.1 Internal parameter values
>   For all the parameters in this section, it is possible to access them directly using their names as index in the tex table, or by using one of the functions tex.get() and tex.set().
>   ...
>   4.13.1.1 Integer parameters
>   The integer parameters accept and return Lua numbers.
>   Read-write:
>   tex.adjdemerits           tex.interlinepenalty
>   ...

Ok, so I want to try `tex.get` - and I was grepping through my texlive installation looking for examples of its use, but no dice. So, I try a little test with whatever I can come up myself, but it segfaults on my machine (using Texlive 2011 updated to frozen version, Ubuntu 10.04); here is the MWE, compiled with `lualatex test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

% this prints tex.get: nil / 1073741823
\directlua{print(""); print("tex.get: " .. tostring(tex.get(boxmaxdepth)) .. " / " .. tex.boxmaxdepth)}

% this segfaults:
% \directlua{print(""); print("tex.get: " .. tostring(tex.get("boxmaxdepth")) ) }

% this segfaults:
% \directlua{print(""); local tgp="boxmaxdepth"; print("tex.get: " .. tostring(tex.get(tgp)) )} % segfault

\end{document}
```

The strange thing is - `tex.boxmaxdepth` does indeed return something, and as per manual, so should `tex.get("boxmaxdepth")`; but any time I try to assign `"boxmaxdepth"` as a string, either directly or through a variable, I get a segfault - only way I don't get a segfault, is if I pass `boxmaxdepth` without quotation marks; which means its being interpreted by `lua` as a variable, which at that point is not set, and thus `nil` (_NB: first time I see a case where a null variable is the only way you don't get a segfault?! `:)` _)

Anyways - I hope it's something me not understanding the `tex.get` syntax, rather than this being a bug; so hopefully someone can clarify this for me `:)`

Comment: Confirmed with the latest `luatex` from svn. Please open a bug report at [the LuaTeX bug tracker](http://tracker.luatex.org).

Comment: workaround: use `tex.boxmaxdepth` directly.

Comment: @TacoHoekwater The segfault seems to occur from __index and get is just a wrapper. The code faults due to an comparison with "4" and an invalid pointer. In any case I come to this bug trying use get on "interactionmode".

Answer (score 3):

Submitted as bug in [0000753: Segfault on using tex.get luatex function - MantisBT](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=753).